# jquery dynamic table generator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built very simple dynamic html table generator using jquery, check following...

```
<button id="addcolumn">Add Column</button>
<button id="addrow">Add Row</button>

<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

<thead id="theads">
    <tr>
        <th class="th" contenteditable>Heading</th>
        <th class="th" contenteditable>Heading</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="tbody">

</tbody>

</table>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    //add head
    $('#addcolumn').click(function(){
        $('<th class="th" contenteditable>Heading</th>').appendTo('thead tr');
    });

    //add row
    $('#addrow').click(function(){
        var totalths = $('.th').length;

        var trcon = '<tr>';
        for (var i = 0; i < totalths; i++) {
            var trcon = trcon + ' <td class="td" align="center" contenteditable>Content</td>';
        }
        var trcon = trcon + ' </tr>';

        $(trcon).appendTo('tbody');

    });

});
```

This currently add `th` on clicking *Add Column* button and add rows on clicking *add row* button with `td = calculated numbers of th` , its working fine, but i am facing a problem, suppose i add 3 columns and 2 rows with 3 tds, but if i want to add more columns after creating 2 rows, it doesn't increase tds in those rows. I hope you understand my problem. thanks. [try this in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prBZS/) as well.

Comment: on your $('#addcolumn') function you're only creating <th> elements - there's no code to add any <td> items

Comment: @jqueryrocks see $('#addrow') function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event handler for the column adding button, just add a cell to the already existing rows:

```
//add head
$('#addcolumn').click(function(){
  $('<th class="th" contenteditable>Heading</th>').appendTo('thead tr');
  $('<td class="td" align="center" contenteditable>Content</td>').appendTo('tbody tr');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $cell = $('<td>', {
        'class': 'td',
        'align': 'center',
        'contenteditable': '',
        'text': 'Content'
    });

    var $header = $('<th>', {
        'class': 'th',
        'contenteditable': '',
        'text': 'Heading'
    });

    $('#addcolumn').click(function() {
        $header.clone().appendTo('thead tr');
        $cell.clone().appendTo('tbody tr');
    });

    $('#addrow').click(function(){
        var $row = $('<tr>');

        $('thead th').each(function() {
            $cell.clone().appendTo($row);
        });

        $row.appendTo('tbody');
    });
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/prBZS/4/**